# From modal to off canvas?

Tags: modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've just started on a new project of my own.
What I would like to do is, on large screens, having a button activating a modal window BUT, on smaller screen (mobiles), I would like that modal window to become an off canvas section and when the button is clicked, the off canvas slides in from the side. Within that modal/off canvas part, there will be a form to fill out. (there will actually be multiple buttons that will need to activate the feature. Think something like multiple thumbnails with each a button to let viewers add comments)

I'm using Bootstrap 3 as my base framework. I would like to minimise the javascript (jQuery) functionalities but I understand I can't completely.

Questions I have, 
do I have to create two HTML sections, one for the modal and one for the off canvas and then programatically hide/show according screen size?

Would it be best to create the form and then thru javascript, add the proper HTML around it according screen size? (though I think this option would be a tough to implement as my javascript skills are "advance beginner" at best)

How would I make the same button switch activation of the modal window or the off canvas form?

It seems to me that I need to detect screen size, no matter how I do the above, what would be the best way to detect the screen size, the safest and surest way?

Thanks for any insights you guys might have on this.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to show code in your questions here, so i also vote to close your question.

> I'm using Bootstrap 3 as my base framework. I would like to minimise
>   the javascript (jQuery) functionalities but I understand I can't
>   completely.

Angular JS decouples Twitter's Bootstrap from javascript. See: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

> Questions I have, do I have to create two HTML sections, one for the
>   modal and one for the off canvas and then programatically hide/show
>   according screen size?

Take a look to the Responsive Utilities: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities
The screen detection of Twitter's Bootstrap is based on CSS media queries.

> How would I make the same button switch activation of the modal window or the off canvas >form?

To give the same button different function based on sceensize you will need javascript / jQuery. See: [Get the size of the screen, current web page and browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/how-to-get-web-page-size-browser-window-size-screen-size-in-a-cross-browser-wa/11744120) you also could consider to use something like [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/), see also http://bassjobsen.weblogs.fm/responsive-banner-ads-2/

Or create two buttons and hide / show them with the the Responsive Utilities.